# Get controller for model in Ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

If I have a reference to a model in Ember, how do I access its controller? If you're in the controller and want to access the model it's as simple as `.get("model")` but the reverse does not seem to hold when you need the controller.

Comment: So your first issue is that accessing a controller from a model is very much against what Ember is all about.  You're far better off using a computed property or a helper in order to get what you need.  What are you trying to do within the model that you need access to the controller for?  A jsfiddle would help here...

Comment: I'd like to access computed properties in other controllers from a given controller within a `hasMany`. In this case there are several "years" of data, and within any given year you need to access computed properties within all other years.

Comment: So you're going cross-years? i.e. A "decade" model hasMany "year", and each "year" needs to access a computed property of another "year"?

Comment: Pretty much! Right now I'm doing a `forEach` on the year models, but that's not getting me where I want. Maybe a better question would be accessing other models' controllers from a given controller in a "decade".

Comment: So you can set the "itemController" property in your parent controller to apply a particicular controller to your child model.  It would help if you could say what you are trying to access exactly, as there are a bunch of different things you could do...

Comment: Essentially each year is computing a total income value, which is a computed property from a variety of values in the model. What I'd like to be able to do is display an overall total income within each year. So how can I iterate over all years in a decade, from within the controller of any one year, and get the computed income value?

Comment: Struggling a bit.  I got some of the way in a fiddle which can easily calculate the overall total, but not for siblings (i.e. not pulling it down from the parent into the child): https://jsfiddle.net/szzo1g6n/6/

Comment: So you have the computed property in the model, is that a good way to do things? I thought computed properties should only be in the controller.

Comment: The property is model-specific, and i'm not affecting it with any external data, so I think that's most appropriate to be inside the model

Comment: I didn't expect that having these computed properties in the model would essentially fix my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it fixed the problem.  I'm going to put my fiddle as an answer as it resolved the issue for you.  You can accept it if you want, but either way it'll be helpful for someone in the future googling this issue no doubt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the combined totals in the parent model, like so:

```
total: function() {
    var amount = 0;
    this.get('years').forEach(function(item) {
        amount += item.get('total');
    });
    return amount;
}.property('years.@each.total')
```

Where "years" is the child model from the hasMany relationship.  This will be dynamically updated any time any of the children change value, using the `@each` keyword.

See this full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szzo1g6n/6/)